# Sensor data via USB

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im working on a project and i want to use a sensor. I can plug in the sensor via usb. I do not need any driver for the sensor. My task is to have an access to the sensor data. I have followed the tutorial on this page: http://clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/ros/Udev%20Rules.html But i dont know if this is my soution. I dont know what to do now. How can i have access to the data in ROS? Do I have to write a wrapper node? If yes, how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298226/sensor-data-via-usb/) by [S.Yildiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36516/s.yildiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2018-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [S.Yildiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36516/s.yildiz/) on 2018-07-23**:
How can I take raw data from the sensors and publish it to a ROS topic?

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2018-07-23**:
How do you usually access the data without ROS? Is there a program you run? Or is it like a mouse that you just plug and play? I think you might need a wrapper to capture the stream of data.

**Comment by [S.Yildiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36516/s.yildiz/) on 2018-07-23**:
I can have access to the data on windows. I have to install a software(Docklight) and configure the setting for the sensor like the baudrate etc. If i do this i get all the data on the software listed. Yes like a mouse. And how can i write a wrapper? is there any tutorial for this?

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2018-07-23**:
ROS works on Linux, did you get it to run on Windows?
I think you should find how the data is being communicated (maybe serial? in that case check http://wjwwood.io/serial/). More info on the sensor would be helpful, but btw if you have to use Windows it seems quite hard to do.

**Comment by [S.Yildiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36516/s.yildiz/) on 2018-07-23**:
So it is a sensor for detecting the range between two modules. No, I dont have to use Windows. There is just a software which can read the data supported on windows. And yes the communicatian is serial.

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2018-07-31**:
Btw I replied down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay with the info provided I think I can sort of give some help.
Check [this past answer too](https://answers.ros.org/question/195391/there-is-an-example-of-a-working-example-of-serial-port-on-ros-indigo-and-c/) btw.

So you in order to get the data in ROS, you need to make a wrapper for your sensor, if you know it's serial communication check the serial support for ROS here.

Also the guy from the answer made a nice simple example of ROS [serial communication here](https://github.com/garyservin/serial-example/blob/master/src/serial_example_node.cpp)

From his code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <serial/serial.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>

serial::Serial ser;

void write_callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg){
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Writing to serial port" << msg->data);
    ser.write(msg->data);
}
    
int main (int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "serial_example_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    ros::Subscriber write_sub = nh.subscribe("write", 1000, write_callback);
    ros::Publisher read_pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("read", 1000);

    try
    {
        ser.setPort("/dev/ttyACM0");
        ser.setBaudrate(9600);
        serial::Timeout to = serial::Timeout::simpleTimeout(1000);
        ser.setTimeout(to);
        ser.open();
    }
    catch (serial::IOException& e)
    {
        ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Unable to open port ");
        return -1;
    }

    if(ser.isOpen()){
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("Serial Port initialized");
    }else{
        return -1;
    }

    ros::Rate loop_rate(5);
    while(ros::ok()){

        ros::spinOnce();

        if(ser.available()){
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("Reading from serial port");
            std_msgs::String result;
            result.data = ser.read(ser.available());
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("Read: " << result.data);
            read_pub.publish(result);
        }
        loop_rate.sleep();

    }
}
```

I think it doesn't get any simpler than that. Once you read the data from the serial port you can use it in your project.
Good luck and happy coding!

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0